# Everytime I run gulp or gulp build local i get AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: build

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I am trying to run 
`gulp`
in my terminal and I get this assertion error. I've uninstalled node and NPM and reinstalled again using brew.
npm version is `6.13.4`
node version `v12.14.1`

My system is MacOS Catalina 10.15.2

Terminal error

```
gulp build
assert.js:374
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: build
    at getFunction (/Users/Designernaruka/Punchh/Practise-Task/bulma/bulma-npm/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/normalizeArgs.js:15:5)
    at map (/Users/Designernaruka/Punchh/Practise-Task/bulma/bulma-npm/node_modules/arr-map/index.js:20:14)
    at normalizeArgs (/Users/Designernaruka/Punchh/Practise-Task/bulma/bulma-npm/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/normalizeArgs.js:22:10)
    at Gulp.series (/Users/Designernaruka/Punchh/Practise-Task/bulma/bulma-npm/node_modules/undertaker/lib/series.js:13:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Designernaruka/Punchh/Practise-Task/bulma/bulma-npm/gulpfile.js:13:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: undefined,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var sass = require('gulp-sass'); 
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); 

gulp.task('sass', function() { 
  return gulp.src('./sass/main.sass')
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
   .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}); 

// Starts a BrowerSync instance 
gulp.task('server', gulp.series('build', 
   function(){ browser.init({server: './_site', port: port}); 

gulp.watch("./sass/main.sass", ['sass']); 
gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload); })); 
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

package.json:

```
{ 
  "name": "bulma-npm",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies":
     {
       "bulma": "^0.8.0"
     },
   "devDependencies":
     { 
       "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
       "gulp": "^4.0.2",
       "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"
     }
 }
```

Comment: ```Package Json
{
  "name": "bulma-npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"
  }
}

```

Comment: ```var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./sass/main.sass')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Starts a BrowerSync instance
gulp.task('server', gulp.series('build', function(){
  browser.init({server: './_site', port: port});

  gulp.watch("./sass/main.sass", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: I have moved your gulpfile and package.json into your question.  In the future please edit your question to add that info - it is much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using gulp v4 this syntax is incorrect:

```
gulp.watch("./sass/main.sass", ['sass']); 

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

That is gulp v3 syntax.  Change it to:

```
gulp.watch("./sass/main.sass", gulp.series('sass')); 

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'));
```

And see a migration guide for going from gulp v3 to v4.  There is a lot of tutorials and code out there that is v3 and it won't work for v4.

Comment: i did same but no success

Comment: Where is your build task you don't show it .  Nevertheless, the errors I pointed out will need to be fixed.  Your code is failing before it gets to those errors.  Probably you are calling build and never defined it unless you have more code to show with that task.

Comment: i am fixing give me sometime.